# How to make an image fill half of the width of a view controller with constant aspect ratio in storyboard?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview

I am trying to make the HexaDec image fill 50% of the width of the view parent while maintaining the square aspect ratio in the storyboard.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding constraints for: `center horizontally in superview`, `width = 0.5 * width_of_superview` and `aspect ratio 1:1`?

Comment: hmm trying to do this in the storyboard. thanks for your help though.

Comment: My comments are for the storyboard, not code. The constraints I mentioned can be added in the storyboard.

Comment: OHHH I will try that!

Comment: Where is the setting for setting width in storyboard?

Comment: Look it up on the internet, it's just control-drag from one part of the view to any other part, release.